# I use TPOT for classification but I found error can help me please

Tags: python

I used TPOT to make classification when write this code

```
tpot =  TPOTClassifier(generations=5,
                       population_size=50,
                       verbosity=2,
                       random_state =42,
                       cv=5,
                       n_jobs=1)
tpot = TPOTClassifier(
                template='FeatureSetSelector-Transformer-Classifier'`enter code here`
                )
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
```

I find this error

> ValueError: No feature is found on the subset list!

Comment: "`\`enter code here\``"?